# Given the content in a single field how do you perform a query that passes the value in a different field, in the same row?

Tags: mysql

```
member  purchase   fruit
1         1        apple
1         2        apple
1         3        banana
1         4        banana
2         1        apple
2         2        apple
2         3        banana
2         4        banana
```

How would I produce the following result set?

SELECT * FROM table where fruit = (the fruit in the record where member = ? and purchase = ?)

For example if `member = 2` and `purchase = 3` the result set would be

```
member  purchase   fruit
2         3        banana
2         4        banana
```

Comment: Why don't you get the other two rows: 1,3,banana and 1,4,banana?

Comment: He probably wants `AND member = 2` in his outer SELECT as well...

Comment: Thanks for looking out for me Jonas, you're correct, I want `AND member = 2` in my outer `SELECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM table where fruit = (the fruit in the record where member = ? and purchase = ?)

You nearly have it. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE fruit =
(
     SELECT fruit FROM yourtable WHERE member = ? AND purchase = ?
)
```

You  may also want to add `AND member = ?` to the end of your query, as mentioned by Jonas Heidelberg in the comments.